Rate of convergence for average of a bounded sequence
Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of numbers such that $x_n \in [0,1]$ for all $n$, and there exists $x^\star$ such that the average, $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, converges to $x^\star$.
Can we say anything about the rate of convergence of the average?
For example, can we say there exists some $r>0$ such that
$$\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i-x^\star\right| = O(1/n^r)?$$
If not, is it possible to show that for any $r>0$, there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ for which the above does not hold?
I know some similar results concerning sequences of i.i.d. random variables, but I am wondering if such results exist for any sequence of real numbers.
